# How to regroup in an Animation/AnimationSet transformations that apply to different views

Tags: android, animation

I am making a little dice game and I have a problem animating my dices:
I have 6 dices (My class Dice extends the TextView class) that I would like to make rotate.
So far, I know how to make them rotate individually (or all together with 6 different animations).

Is it possible to regroup in one animation or in an animationset these rotations so that with an Animation.AnimationListener I would be able to wait the end of those animations to run further instructions?

Thank you by advance for your help.

Gontran